# How to give a two different color to the list items of a customized list-view in android?

Tags: android, listview, background-color

Can anyone tell me how to give a two different color to the list items of a customized list-view in android?
Like the below image.Is it possible?

[image]

Suggestion please

Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: Yup. It is possible.Post your code of ListView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you,

Insert this code in your custom list adapter,

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater lInflater;
    List<String> data;

    ListAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        ctx = context;
        this.data = data;
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        }
// The logic is added here

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.artists_list_backgroundcolor);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.artists_list_background_alternate);
        }

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.yourText)).setText(data.get(position));

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: @A correct this `.setBackgroundColor(.....)` instead of `.setBackgroundResource(....)`

Comment: @SimplePlan: yes you can use setBackgroundColor, in my case i used the color values from drawable folder. :)

Comment: @Aerrow After using your suggested code, when im clicking anyone of the item from the listview, it is not blinking,usually if we click the  any item from the listview means it will blink the whole row by default right? but in this case why its now working?

Comment: can you plz, add this line in your listview, android:cacheColorHint="#b8bc6f". let me know once it working.

Comment: @Aerrow No, its not working, its just getting some spaces between items with color you mentioned above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54918/discussion-between-prabu-and-aerrow).

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your Adapter(BaseAdapter):

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {


            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                yourView.setBackground("First Color ");
            } else {
                yourView.setBackground("second Color ");
            }

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a check in getView() Method of Custom List Adapter use this code:

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    if (v == null) {
        Logger.show(Log.INFO, TAG, " getview v = null");

        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.categories_list_item, null);

        if (position % 2 == 0) {
            v.setBackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.red_color));
            // Declare red_color in color.xml as: <color name="red_color">#DF0101</color>
        } else {
            v.setBackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_color));
            // Declare blue_color in color.xml as: <color name="blue_color">#FFFFFF</color>
        }


    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

    return v;
}
```